# What are the considerations using two DC-DC converts in serial or sharing a common input?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

In my design I need two power sources. They are 3.3V and 5V.
I am using two DC/DC converters for this.

Please bear with me as I am fairly new in designing circuits.

[image: For example, these two are sharing common input from a 12V source.]

What if I feed **R-78E3.3-0.5** from **R-78E5.0-0.5**, will there be any important different?  (For a minute, forget about extra current stress on the 5V converter.)

I appreciate for your inputs from now.

Comment: You talk about DCDC converters, generally we use the name DCDC converters for **switching** converters. In your schematic you appear to use **linear regulators** (not DCDC converters). I can tell because I do not see any inductors which are a crucial element of most DCDC converters.

Comment: @FakeMoustache: R-78EX-0.5 series are switchting convertes which are designed to be compatible to linear regulators. There is no (external) inductance needed.

Comment: Oh, OK, I stand corrected. I don't use that type (too expensive). Also naming them IC1 and IC3 made me assume they're LDOs.

Comment: I used them for a term paper. If anyone had told me how expensive they are, I would have used something else.

Comment: I have that chance to use those expensive pieces (appx. 3-4 euros each). As per my previous design experiences they are quite efficient up to 93% (as per the datasheet). They are barely mild warm in continuous operation. Thank for bringing another details about them for the records.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R-78E3.3-0.5 needs a minimum input voltage of 6V. So there is a important difference: It won't work.

If it would you would have less efficency and more load on your 5V supply.

Comment: Yes, you are right about that. I missed that point, it won't work as per the datasheet, minimum input must be 6v. If you allow me to ask, what if I use LDO after 5V converter instead of that converter?

Comment: Then it will work, but efficency is even worse.